# Don't 'artifactoryPublish' when running Artifactory Jenkins Plugin

Tags: jenkins, gradle, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

Is it possible to do a `gradle.run` (see below), without running the `artifactoryPublish` task? I thought I could accomplish this by specifying the tasks parameter, but the plugin appears to add the task back in. For example, the following:

```
def server = Artifactory.server('artifactory-primary')
def gradle = Artifactory.newGradleBuild()
gradle.resolver server: server, repo: 'gradle-all-virtual'
gradle.deployer server: server, repo: 'gradle-libs-snapshot-local'
gradle.deployer.mavenCompatible = true
gradle.useWrapper = true
gradle.usesPlugin = true

def buildInfo = gradle.run(
    rootDir: ".",
    buildFile: 'build.gradle',
    tasks: 'build',
    switches: '--no-daemon -x check')        
server.publishBuildInfo buildInfo
```

Results in:

```
...
gradlew -x check build artifactoryPublish -b build.gradle
...
```

When what I really want is:

```
...
gradlew -x check build -b build.gradle
...
```

Ultimately I want to build in one stage and deploy in another.

---

The same snippet but with references to artifactory removed from my Gradle file and with Tamir's addition added in:

```
def server = Artifactory.server('artifactory-primary')
def gradle = Artifactory.newGradleBuild()
gradle.resolver server: server, repo: 'gradle-all-virtual'
gradle.deployer server: server, repo: 'gradle-libs-snapshot-local'
gradle.deployer.mavenCompatible = true
gradle.deployer.deployArtifacts = false
gradle.useWrapper = true
gradle.usesPlugin = false

def buildInfo = gradle.run(
    rootDir: ".",
    buildFile: 'build.gradle',
    tasks: 'build',
    switches: '--no-daemon -x check')        
server.publishBuildInfo buildInfo
```

Produces the same result.

Comment: Have you tried 'publishtomavenlocal' ?

Comment: @RuchikaSharma I can't see what that'd accomplish. Could you please provide a bit more reasoning?

Answer (score 4):

The artifactoryPublish task is added by default, you can see that in the [Jenkins Artifactory plugin code](https://github.com/JFrogDev/jenkins-artifactory-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jfrog/hudson/pipeline/steps/ArtifactoryGradleBuild.java#L175-L181).
If you prefere not to deploy artifacts to artifactory you can do so by configuring deployer.deployArtifacts = false.
In your case:

```
gradle.deployer.deployArtifacts = false
```

If you want to build you project in two phases you can once build it with deployArtifacts=false and in the second time to build it with deployArtifacts=true

Comment: Thanks Tamir, I tried this as well (omitted from my original question). No change, see sample in question.